# Multiplying certain value in array based on certain condition in another array and storing value in a new array?

Tags: java, arrays, store

I am creating a program based on arrays that helps calculate the stipend for a number of tutors who assist students with their skills.  The program takes in the number of tutors, then proceeds with the tutors name, asks how many students that tutor has assisted and then asks what degree level the tutor has (BS, MS, PhD).  The tutor will be payed a different amount of money based on the degree level they have.  So if the first tutor (Bill) has taught 5 students and has a PhD (which is $20 per student), then he will be payed $100.00 and, so on and so forth for the other tutors (MS = 15.00 per student, BS = 9.50 per student).

My problem is that when I have entered all the data, I just get 0.0 for the pay column and 0.0 for the total stipend.  What I am trying to do is based on the degree entered in the degree array, you multiply the taught array (aka the number of students taught) by the amount of money per student, and then store that number in a new array called stipend.  I have re-arranged, re-named, and done about everything I can think of to try and get the stipend to show up but I am running out of options and becoming very frustrated.  So if anyone could please help me it would be greatly appreciated.

```
        for(int pay=0; pay<numOfTutors; pay++) {
            if (degree[pay] == "BS") {
                stipend[pay] = taught[pay] * 9.50;
            }
            else if (degree[pay] == "MS") {
                stipend[pay] = taught[pay] * 15.00;
            }
            else if (degree[pay] == "PhD") {
                stipend[pay] = taught[pay] * 20.00;
            }
            sum+=stipend[pay];
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Stepping through it line by line?

Comment: Yes, I have gone through it step by step, re-arranged, re-named, took things out, put things in, and still no avail.  My pay column just keeps coming up 0.0.

Comment: It helps to provide SO with reduced code samples. I.e. remove all inessential code (for example replace input/output with some hardcoded dummy data), while making sure it's possible to copy/paste your code into an IDE, add some boilerplate, and have your problem manifest right away.

Comment: Also, "parallel arrays" are confusing. Consider creating a class to hold the data that's in `names`, `degree`, `stipend`, and `taught`.

Comment: Duly noted, thanks for the useful input, I'm still working on the project, I just needed help on that one part before I went any further, thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `==` operator, instead of the `.equals()` method, to check for string equality. You should change the lines of the form

```
degree[pay] == "some_string"
```

to

```
degree[pay].equals("some_string")
```

Or, if you want case insensitive matching, you could use

```
degree[pay].equalsIgnoreCase("some_string")
```

Here's what's going on: when you write `degree[pay] = "some_string"`, you are checking for **reference equality**, which will not work for what you are doing, because a constant string and a generated string will not have equal references. The `.equals()` method will check for **equal values**, which is what you want.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH, I can't believe it was something so simple I looked over, I was basing my (degree[pay] = "some_string") off of a previous project and just completely forgot about the (.equals).  Thank you so much once again.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark an answer (preferably mine :) if it answers your question!

Comment: No problem! Have fun programming :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `String#equals` to compare `String` content. The `==` operator is used to compare `Object` references. Because the references of the 2 values being compared are not equals, then none of the pay adjustments for the array `stipend` take place. Replace

```
if (degree[pay] == "BS") {
```

with

```
if (degree[pay].equals("BS")) {
```

Similarly for "MS" and "PhD" String checks.

Comment: Yep just found out from another poster, thank you though, much appreciated!